# Can you use rename() in R to rename a variable by referencing a variable that stores a string?

Tags: r, dplyr, rename

I am trying to write a function that takes a data frame and a string to rename a variable in the data frame as the string. If I have the following data frame `df` and variable `x`:

```
    var1    var2
A    1        1
B    1        1

x = "new_var"
```

I want to create a function that will take the data frame and string as arguments and return the following data frame:

```
    var1    new_var
A    1        1
B    1        1
```

My initial thought was do create something like the following:

```
dplyr_f <- function(df, x){
    new_df <- df %>%
        rename(x = var2)
    return(new_df)
}

dplyr_f(df, x)
```

But this returns:

```
    var1      x
A    1        1
B    1        1
```

instead of the second column being named new_var.

Is there anyway I can make rename() use the value of a variable like `x` instead of it thinking I literally want to rename the variable "x"? Or maybe there's a better solution?

I would be piping the output into other dplyr functions, so I am looking for a dplyr-based solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is use the `bang bang` operator, ie `!!`:

```
dplyr_f <- function(df, x){
  new_df <- df %>%
    rename(!!x := var2)
  return(new_df)
}
dplyr_f(df, x)
  var1 new_var
A    1       1
B    1       1
```